# Loading an ado file on Stata

Tags: stata

I had a query regarding loading third party programmes onto Stata.

I am using Stata version 13.1, and trying to use a program defined in a third-party ado file, written by the World Bank (accessible [here](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/health/publication/analyzing-health-equity-using-household-survey-data)).

I have tried putting the ado file in my `C:/ado/plus` folder, which is the default directory listed on Stata.

However, when I try to run dominance using:

```
dominance y [aw=wt], sortvar(x)
```

Stata throws up the following error:

> plugin not loaded or not available: use the adoonly option

I can't find any information on how to load the plugin.

It’s making it impossible for me to use this programme and run my analysis, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `adoonly` option corresponds to the user-written command `locpoly`, a requirement of `dominance`.

The author of dominance assumes you have the plugin for `locpoly` installed. If you don't want to install it, then you need to modify the `dominance` ado-file so it will run with `locpoly, ... adoonly`.

The option is to install the plugin for `locpoly`. The article introducing the command is [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0053). Note that `locpoly` was superseded by `lpoly`, a Stata official command. Find a Statalist thread with relevant information [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-05/msg00691.html). Read the complete thread, as it has additional, relevant information, related to system architecture.

For more information on Stata plugins, check http://www.stata.com/plugins/.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was running the code with the -locpoly- command without the adoonly option. However, I decided to use -lpoly- and updated the dominance.ado file.

However, now I get a new error: standard error evaluated to missing already preserved r(621). 

What does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, I seemed to have figured it out. It worked with the -locpoly- command by adding the adoonly option. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at `search r(621)`, to get more details on the error.

Comment: Yes. Although `locpoly` was superseded, if some old user-written command uses it, there should be no problem with having it installed to comply with the requirement.

Comment: Note that if you download the st0053_3.pkg package-description file for `locpoly`, you'll see that there's a plugin for each of the following platforms: AIX DECALPHA HP IRIX LINUX LINUX.C MAC SOL64 SOLARIS WIN. Noticeably absent are more modern platforms, including WIN64A (64-bit x86-64) and all modern MACINTEL variants. Installing a plugin is not really a choice. If it was not installed, it's not available for your setup. The solution here, as Roberto pointed out, is to edit the `dominance` ado file.